# Can I get some advice on my speed using wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ethernet, connection, speed

I have AT&T DSL and, as expected, the speed isn't the best. They made me pay a high price for a cheap router and modem (2in1). I've had the router for a few years. Lately, the speed has been horrendous. Before, my speeds have been about 320 kilobytes per second. The speeds maybe around 400 kilobytes per second using an ethernet cable directly. Now, using wifi, I get maybe 20 kilobytes per second, and 120 kilobytes per second using an ethernet cable. I had AT&T adjust the speeds and the wifi stayed at 20-30 kilobytes per second. I have a Netgear 7550. Here are the specs:

> Blockquote
>   ADSL Device configured for AT&T DSL services
>   LAN Interface: (4) Ethernet 10/100BASE-T (RJ-45) with auto-crossover and a high-powered 802.11n Wireless Access Point
>   WAN Interface: ADSL, ADSL2, ADSL2+ (RJ-11)
>   Light indicators: Power, Ethernet, DSL, Internet, and Activity
>   Private or Public LAN IP address
>   Manufacturer: NETGEAR

I feel like buying a better router would help, but I'm not completely sure. My maximum speed is supposed to be 3.21 megabits per second if that is any help with anything. Can I get some advice or help? Thanks a ton!

Comment: 1) Your maximum speed may well be 3.21 mbps.  It doesn't sound like you've exceeded that, which is what "maximum" means.  2) Hardware doesn't get tired and slow down.  It's capable of what you got initially.  If you're not achieving that now, it's either because something has changed in you computer (settings, applications, background processes, etc.), or AT&T isn't providing the same level of service.  A different router won't make any difference in your case since something else is limiting performance to less than the current router's capabilities.

Comment: Move to the Network Engineering site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With wireless, there are a number of things you can check or try to see if you can improve the available bandwidth.  You really aren't even beginning to stretch the limits of the wireless or wired connections, though.

1. If just the wireless is slow, avoiding interference is best.

1a. You can try changing the wireless channel that the Netgear is set to, use 1, 6, or 11 (if in the US) if there aren't many wireless networks in range, or 4 or 9 if there are more than 12.

1b. You can also try moving the router to try to avoid interference.  Closer or above where you tend to use the wireless is best, and avoid thick walls or large metal beams or pipes.

2. If both your wired and wireless speeds are horrendous connected directly to the Netgear Router, address this with AT&T further.  They should be able to give you a speed you can reasonably expect, your router supports ADSL2+ which can get up to 12 Mbps down and 1.5 Mbps up, and everything else listed for specs on that router aren't going to be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the router should be your last resort. You may want to check your router settings before you do this. If the router is provided by the Internet Service Provider (ISP), you can directly have them check the settings.

Usually, devices provided by the ISP are 2 in one. And this is generally not the issue. Also, if you do decide to go with a new router, you may not be able to get product recommendations on this site.

Also, if you do get your own router, you will need to have some knowledge to manually tinker with the settings and the ISP will generally not help with this